# How to keep track of all the components used by my Django app

Tags: python, django

I've been developing a Django app and in the process I installed a couple of component using pip (e.g. pip install django-ajax-selects). I just realized that those components aren't installed in my app directory but somewhere which is machine specific.

First, how do I keep track of all the components I installed. Second, how do I install those component in my app directory so that I can move the code from machine to machine without having to do "pip install ...".

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use virtualenv.

Create a virtualenv, activate it, install what you need, then do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to create a file listing all your requirements. Then on your new machine (also inside a virtualenv) you can do `pip install -r requirements.txt` to reinstall all those libraries.

Comment: Bears mentioning that there's no *safe* way to not have to do `pip install` for each environment, because every environment is different and the packages must be built for the environment they're running in. But, using a requirements file, as Daniel suggests, at least let's you easily install all the same packages in each destination.

Comment: I like the idea of having a list of all the packaes. However, how can I backup those packages? What happen if a component is removed from the repository?

Comment: You use pip freeze command to backup the list of packages and their versions into a requirements file. Because the versions will be backuped, there should be no compatibility problems. http://blog.yourlabs.org/103518532